# generating django admin console for a already existing mysql db schema

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a msql DB within with i have my tables.The tables has proper constraints like primary keys, foreign keys, auto increment.I love django admin console and i want to generate admin console for my db.

Now my application is completely developed in java.I want to run seperate django app which will use the same db and provide me with admin console by which i can manipulate data in those tables.

I am not a python developer so i dont want to write classes corresponding to tables,Is there any way to do this?Can i do reverse engineering ?Can i generate python classes and django admin console automaticall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/legacy-databases/